# TFS - Branching just one project in a solution

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, branching-and-merging

I have solution in VS 2017 contains 4 projects - asp.net project, windows form project, SSIS project and console project. Now in WinForm project we are going to add lots of new features which we plan to release after 9-10 months, so I am thinking to create a branch for WinForm Dev branch. Here is my solution and folder structure...

```
MySol
   MySln.sln
   ConsoleApp
   WebApp
   WinForm     (Main)
   WinnFormDev (Branch)
   SSIS Pkges
```

I successfully created Dev branch but when I open a solution in VS, I don't see my Dev branch so I can't make any change. My goal to is work in Dev branch and I may have to make some changes in WinForm main branch and other projects during 9-10 months development, I will always merge those changes in WinForm Dev, once all new features are added in Dev branch (after 9-10 months) I will merge into main and get rid off Dev branch. Is this possible? or I have to branch whole solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in the Dev branch on local.

For example, I have two branches on my side:

[image]

In Visual Studio, you can first clone the repository, and then select the Dev branch here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am using TFS and my main project is part of the solution. Can you please explain how I can do this on TFS?